# Why do blackbodies emit all frequencies of light?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, thermal-radiation

In Quantum Mechanics - Concepts and Applications by Zettili, he states that an ideal blackbody can emit light across the entire spectrum. Why is this? In other words, what is the physical process that could cause this phenomena?

Comment: So basically, because there are many different atoms & molecules interacting, the number of possible states ( in this case frequencies of light) goes up exponentially. Is this correct, or am I wrong?

Comment: There are many ways to get continuum absorption/emission in different substances. The bottom line is: if there isn't then those materials do not emit as blackbodies.